# Unable to compile class for JSP after Jquery UI.js file included

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I have a small problem in my web application. 
Situation is that when i include jquery ui.js and also some css file of jquery ui my entire page crashed. but when i again remove the jquery-ui.js file entire pages loads smoothly. I have tested the same js and css file in an html and everything works.

Here is the short details
IDE : Netbeans 8
JVM : 1.7.0_21 X64
Tomcat: 8
Jquery-UI : v1.10.4

my jsp page looks like

**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript"><%@include file="WEB-INF/script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" %></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"><%@include file="WEB-INF/script/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" %></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"><%@include file="WEB-INF/script/bootstrap.min.js" %></script>
        <style type="text/css"> <%@include file="WEB-INF/style/bootstrap.css" %></style>        
        <style type="text/css"> <%@include file="WEB-INF/style/bootstrap.min.css" %></style>
        <style type="text/css"> <%@include file="WEB-INF/style/r.css" %></style>
        <style type="text/css"> <%@include file="WEB-INF/style/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" %></style>        
        <title>Home</title>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

**
and the error on jsp page is as follows

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [51] in the generated java file: [C:\Tomcat 8\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\work\Catalina\localhost\FashionWorld\org\apache\jsp\Home_jsp.java]
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:355)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please help me.. i still dont understand whats wrong with this particular jquery-ui.js file..

One more thing even after I remove other js files like bootstrap and jQuery js file still I am getting the same error.
Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the below lines

`<script type="text/javascript"><%@include file="WEB-INF/script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" %></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"><%@include file="WEB-INF/script/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" %></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"><%@include file="WEB-INF/script/bootstrap.min.js" %></script>
        <style type="text/css"> <%@include file="WEB-INF/style/bootstrap.css" %></style>

        <style type="text/css"> <%@include file="WEB-INF/style/bootstrap.min.css" %></style>
        <style type="text/css"> <%@include file="WEB-INF/style/r.css" %></style>
        <style type="text/css"> <%@include file="WEB-INF/style/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" %></style>`

Do the following things:

1. Move the files from `WEB-INF/script/* to WebContent/script/*` and `WEB-INF/style/* to WebContent/style/*`
2. Change the above code in JSP to the below:

> ```
> <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style/bootstrap.css"
> ```
>
> type="text/css">

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"></link>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style/r.css" type="text/css"></link>

 < script type="text/javascript"
 src="CONTEXT_ROOT/script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="CONTEXT_ROOT/script/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script> <script
 type="text/javascript"
 src="CONTEXT_ROOT/script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Where CONTEXT_ROOT should be replaced with `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

Comment: For some reason I was not able to put the <script tags within Code tags when I added the {pageContext.request.contextPath}. So I apologize for the not clear formatted message.